# v-for loop with forms is not assigning the values

Tags: forms, vue.js, v-for

I have an error

`Cannot assign to read only property 'description' of object '#<Object>'`

when trying to change the value of `description`.

I have an array of objects `[{description, amount}]`. It is passed from the parent component. I guess the problem is with the `v-for` loop. Why do I get this error and how could I solve it?

```
    props: {
        data: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            object: {...this.data.object},
        };
    },
```

```
            <template v-for="(item, index) in object.items">
                  <input v-model="item.description"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed the issue. I deep cloned the object and it works good now.